# Crear Web Api con NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure, azure-sql

Tengo la necesidad de crear una Web API con NetCore 3.1 con el siguiente propósito. Tengo creado una base de datos en Azure SQL Database, tengo creado un App Service en Azure.

Lo que deseo hacer es crear el Servicio Web API para que mi app de escritorio(Windows Forms) se comunique con la base de datos que esta en Azure.

¿Como debo implementar el servicio Web API para poder conectarme a una base de datos?, me imagino que en la implementación debe tener la cadena de conexión en un archivo appConfig, ¿solo eso?

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes poner todas tu claves secretas en archivo appsettings.json e iniciar la configuración en tu clase Startup. Mi configuración:

```
//appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PruebaContext": "Server=1.11.111.11;Database=1111;User ID=11;Password=1111"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AppS3Bucket": ""
}
```

Cabe mencionar que todos los valores con '1' son de ejemplo y deben ser reemplazados por los reales. Mi clase Startup luce similar a:

```
//Startup.cs
namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        ...
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            //Se hace ferefencia al dbcontext dada por appsettings
            services.AddDbContext<Models.AcqPOSPruebaContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PruebaContext")));

            //Configuracion de CORS
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin", 
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
            });
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Para desplegar tu back te recomiendo [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/net-core-3-support-in-azure-functions-now-in-preview/). Saludos

Answer (score 1):

no es necesario ninguna conexión, desde mi punto de vista si ya creaste la Web Api o la estas creando solo necesitas consumirla. La api te botara la información en JSON de forma serializada, lo único que tienes que hacer es hacer la http request con el url de la info que necesitas y deserializarlo...
Aqui tengo un ejemplo:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string baseUri = "http://localhost:9874/api/people";

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        string result = client.DownloadString(baseUri);
        IEnumerable<Person> people =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Person>>(result);
        return people;
    }
```